# Are namespaces connected to specific libraries?

Tags: c++

So we have `#include <iostream>` and using `namespace std`. I though that's how it works: when we use functions from libraries, like `cin`, we should write `name_of_library::function`, but additionally to `#include` we can use namespace library_name and don't write `name_of_library::function` anymore.

But then I understood that `std` and `iostream` are not straightforward connected -- we don't write `iostream::cin`, after all. So `std` is a namespace for some default libraries, like `iostream`, `fstream`, `vector`? How do we work with non-default libraries then?

Comment: Libraries have  no direct relationship with namespaces, whatsoever. A library can define objects in multiple namespaces. Different libraries can define objects in the same namespace. Welcome to C++!

Comment: "How do we work with non-default libraries then" all depend on these libs,. You can create your own lib and use or not namespaces, you decide, even the goal when making a lib to distribute it is to  limit the possible name conflict  ... which is the goal of the namespaces

Comment: @SamVarshavchik So every library is in some namespace? Default libraries use std and other libraries have their own namespaces (named just like a library)? Because I don't understand how to use libraries without namespaces

Comment: @bruno but how can I use a library without namespace? I can't use iostream without std

Comment: @Chaotic_Neutral because *iostream* is in *std*, but when you use old libraries defining *strcmp* (header `#include <string.h>`) or `printf`(*stdio.h*) etc there is no namespace so you use names directely without prefix nor `using namespace`

Comment: No, there is no law that says that every library must define symbols only in some namespace.

Comment: It is possible to wrap a library in your own namespace, e.g. `namespace wrapper { #include <lib/file>; }`, which can help with conflicting names

Answer (score 5):

A namespace name can be whatever the library author wants it to be.

A library can also contain multiple namespaces - and/or nested namespaces.

There is also no requirement that a library uses a namespace *at all*.

There's absolutely no relationship between library names, file names and namespace names etc (unless the library author chooses to create/maintain such a relation).